# Why isn't the price of BTC rapidly growing due to WannaCry?

Tags: trading, exchange-rate, value, price-volatility

This occurred to me today: the ongoing ransomware attack (started on May 12) caused by the WannaCry virus infected over 230 000 computers so far (source: Wikipedia). This probably means that a lot of these people (and/or companies) will pay the demanded price in Bitcoin, which, intuitively, should lead to a rapid growth of BTC value.

However, as it can be seen in the image below (BTC-USD chart taken from Kraken), this isn't happening. This is slightly confusing, so I'm looking for an explanation. 
[image]

Comment: This is a way to speculative question for the forum here. We are more developper oriented, on how to code. We ususally don't predict the future, though of course we accept the rise in price :-)
Maybe ask in one of the reddits (https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/new/).

Comment: You can just as easily argue this will drop the price as people fear it will result in negative publicity and possibly even a regulatory crackdown.

Answer (score 1):

I've read somewhere that around $6000 had been paid in total; at roughly $500 per ransom that's 12 people who actually paid. That's a speck in the ocean.